# How to push Json Array Dynamically within Json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    dataLayer = [];
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'pre-addToCart',
        'ecommerce': {
            'currencyCode': 'EUR',
            'add': {
                'products': [] // I need to insert the products data here directly instead of pushing it 
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the manipulation I'm doing after the object has been created. I want this to be done directly within the object. Any thoughts?

```
var length = $(".booking-ticket-table tbody tr").length;
for (var i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
    var prod_sku = $(".booking-ticket-table  td.alpha")[i].textContent.trim().split(/\s/).join('');
    var prod_name = $(".booking-ticket-table  td.alpha")[i].textContent.trim();     //Prod name
    var prod_price = $(".booking-ticket-table td.omega")[i].textContent.trim().replace('£','');     //Prod Price
    var prod_qty = $(".booking-ticket-table  td:nth-of-type(2) input")[i].getAttribute("value");        //Prod Qty

    dataLayer[0].ecommerce.add.products.push({
        "id":"1232",
        "sku":prod_sku,
        "name": prod_name,
        "price": prod_price,
        "quantity": prod_qty 
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, apart from using strings instead of the variable names when pushing the new item to the array. What exactly are you trying to improve?

Comment: Thanks :) I need to insert the products data here directly instead of pushing it

Comment: Pls help @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I don't know what you mean. `push` is the best method of adding items to an array, so I'm confused why you would want an alternative.

Comment: That's a different scenario here, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try encapsulating your second code block into a function. Not much difference really, but a bit more modular:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 
dataLayer = [];
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'pre-addToCart',
    'ecommerce': {
        'currencyCode': 'EUR',
        'add': {
            'products': buildProducts() //returns the array
        }
    }
});
```

buildProducts would look something like:

```
function buildProducts(){
    var theProducts = [];
    var length = $(".booking-ticket-table tbody tr").length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        var prod_sku = $(".booking-ticket-table  td.alpha")[i].textContent.trim().split(/\s/).join('');
        var prod_name = $(".booking-ticket-table  td.alpha")[i].textContent.trim();
        var prod_price = $(".booking-ticket-table td.omega")[i].textContent.trim().replace('£','');
        var prod_qty = $(".booking-ticket-table  td:nth-of-type(2) input")[i].getAttribute("value");

        theProducts.push({
            "id":"1232",
            "sku":prod_sku,
            "name": prod_name,
            "price": prod_price,
            "quantity": prod_qty 
        });
    }

    return theProducts;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain How buildProducts() returns array